# Using regex in Grep for Windows command line

Tags: regex, windows, cmd, grep

I want to capture all lines which contain **exactly** 3 fields, where a field is any string (possibly empty) followed by a `|` (and there may be some final text at the end of the line).

I managed to build a `regex` which seems to do exactly what I want

```regex
^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}[^\|]*$
```

and when I try it on [101regex](https://regex101.com/r/XYTyR2/3) it seems to work just fine.

However, I am having problems to run this `regex` on the Windows command line via `grep` and I guess it has something to do with the proper escaping.

I tried

```
grep -E '^^(?:[^^^\^|]*^\^|){3}[^^^\^|]*$' test.txt
grep -E '^^(?:[^^^|]*^|){3}[^^^|]*$' test.txt
```

but nothing helped. Any ideas?

---

**Test Input**

```
0|1|2|3
0|1|2|
|1|2|3
|1|2|
|1|2
|1|
0|1|2
0|1|
|1|2|3|4
|1|2|3|
0|1|2|3|4
0|1|2|3|
```

---

Comment: if you can use awk instead, you can avoid regex altogether: `awk -F'|' 'NF==4'` (not sure about quoting on windows though)

Comment: using regex101 for tools like grep won't work because there are many differences in syntax and features, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: Thx Sundeep for the pointer. Any online tools like `regex101` which I could use to test my `regex`? I am aware that there are (not so) subtle differences between the engines, but I also feel that most of the times a certain flag or alike helps to make the `regex`work. But I feel that here the problem is more due to escaping on the windows prompt...

Comment: not aware of online regex tester for cli tools.. however, if you want to test the cmd in unix-like environment, sites like https://ideone.com/ and https://repl.it/ can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `grep`, when you use POSIX ERE regex engine, you need to avoid backslashes in bracket expressions and non-capturing groups:

```
grep -E "^([^|]*\|){3}[^|]*$" test.txt
```

Here, `[^\|]` is turned into `[^|]` (since POSIX bracket expressions do not treat escaped chars as regex escapes) and `(?:` is replaced with `(`, i.e. the group was made capturing since non-capturing ones are not supported.

See proof it is working:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but have you considered that this should work on Windows **`cmd`**? Because I get the following error: `'){3}[|]*$'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @thothal Could you please provide the exact environment where you are using `grep` what `grep` you are using?  `grep` version? Is it Win10? Or some Linux WSL in Win10?

Comment: `grep --version` yields `grep (GNU grep) 3.1`. I am running grep on the Windows command prompt, invoked by `cmd.exe`

Comment: And as hinted, it all has to do with proper escaping for the Windows command prompt.

Comment: @thothal So, you are using [*Grep for Windows*](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm),  use double quotes around the pattern.