# Find all unique occurrences of first 3 char, count number of occurrences and write output to a file

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, grep, switch-statement

I have a text file with over 250 million lines. Each line has a 3 digit area code followed by a comma and a 7 digit number.

Sample Input File:
201,2220000
201,5551212
310,5552481
376,1239876
443,0002222
572,8880099
...

I would like to generate an output file which lists each unique area code and the number of occurrences of that area code (only looking at the first 3 characters of each line).

Example output (area code, count):
201, 44556
202, 34529
...

I am working in a Windows 10 environment.

After considerable research, I was able to use the Switch function with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) in PowerShell to achieve something very close. The problem with this solution is that I need to know which area codes I am looking for (and I don't know all the area codes listed in this file).

I would like to modify the solution such that it finds all unique area codes and then run the code.

Here's what I have tried:

---

1. Say, I want to search for the following four area codes: 201,202,203,205
2. My text file is datafile.txt

```
$count1 = 0
$count2 = 0
$count3 = 0
$count4 = 0
switch -File C:\datafile.txt -Exact -Regex { '201\S{8}' { ++$count1 } }
Write-Output "Area Code 201: $($count1)" | Format-Table | Out-File "C:\summary.txt" -append
switch -File C:\datafile.txt -Exact -Regex { '202\S{8}' { ++$count2 } }
Write-Output "Area Code 202: $($count2)" | Format-Table | Out-File "C:\summary.txt" -append
switch -File C:\datafile.txt -Exact -Regex { '203\S{8}' { ++$count3 } }
Write-Output "Area Code 203: $($count3)" | Format-Table | Out-File "C:\summary.txt" -append
switch -File C:\datafile.txt -Exact -Regex { '205\S{8}' { ++$count4 } }
Write-Output "Area Code 204: $($count4)" | Format-Table | Out-File "C:\summary.txt" -append
```

This code generates the file summary.txt and appends the counts to the area codes. However, I think this is inefficient as:

1. I need to know all the area codes that are in this datafile.
2. I have to add 3 lines of code for every additional area code.

Would appreciate any help improving this code or for using an alternate solution (I found a thread on Stackoverflow that uses grep [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229157/using-regex-in-grep-for-windows-command-line](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but it has the same limitation - you need to know what string you are searching for.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of maybe 10 lines from those 250,000,000?

Comment: Great, edit it into your question

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Comment: `Import-Csv .\Input.txt -Header area |Group-Object -Property area -NoElement |Export-Csv .\Output.csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understood correctly, there is no [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) needed here, just [`.SubString(0, 3)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0) to get the first 3 characters from each line and a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) to ensure unique codes and efficiency.

Indeed, [`switch -File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) is awesome for this task and should be used to read your file. Otherwise, for simplicity and also keeping it efficient, you could use [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0).

```
$map = @{ }
switch -File path\to\source\file.txt {
    Default {
        $map[$_.Substring(0, 3)] += 1
    }
}

$map.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Code  = $_.Key
        Count = $_.Value
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\resultOfUniqueCodes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The Export-Csv instead of Set-Content formatted the output perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Matteru happy to help :) I'm curious how long it took to process the 250 million lines?

Comment: Almost 10 min (but did not really hog too much of system resources while running). The file was a little over 247 million lines.

Comment: @Matteru thats pretty nice, yeah the memory usage should be super low because the `switch` is reading line by line and the hash only adds unique key / values composed of a string and an integer so that's really nothing from memory perspective

Comment: Is it possible to modify the output file to add the input filename in the first column and Code in 2nd column and Count in 3rd? I have a set of smaller files and wanted to see if I can have just one output file that will have data appended.

Comment: @Matteru sorry for the late response. yeah for sure you can, I assume you're using `Get-ChildItem` and then inside the loop using this logic posted in my answer? if so, in the last part of the code, inside the `[pscustomobject]` you could add a new property, for example, `FilePath = $_.FullName`. If that doesn't make sense, please ask a new question showing what you currently have to loop the files and reference this question if needed

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I was able to use `Get-ChildItem` and loop it using `foreach($file in Get-ChildItem`  As I wanted only the filename added to the output, I used `File = $file.name` inside `[pscustomobject]` and added `-Append` to `Export-csv`

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents for a streaming approach - trying to avoid everything that's comparatively slow, like `ForEach-Object`, `pscustomobject` and `Export-Csv`.

```sh
# Create a scriptblock to be able to pipe output of foreach loop
& { 
    foreach( $line in [IO.File]::ReadLines( 'input.txt' ) ) { 
        $line.Substring( 0, 3 )
    }
} | Group-Object -NoElement | & {
    begin {
        'Code,Count'
    }
    process {
        '{0},{1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Count
    }
} | Set-Content output.csv
```

**Remarks:**

- `foreach( $line in [IO.File]::ReadLines( 'input.txt' ) )` processes the input file lazily, so it's **not** read into memory as a whole. This works because `ReadLines` returns an iterator (not a collection) which `foreach` understands. As mentioned by others `ReadLines` is considered one of the fastest ways for line-by-line processing of text files, while still providing ease-of-use (compared to using .NET streams for instance).
- `Group-Object -NoElement` just counts the number of occurences of unique input elements, propably using an internal hashtable, so it should be as fast as a manually created hashtable (not measured though - it would be really interesting).
- Piping from `Group-Object` to a script block is much faster than `ForEach-Object` with a script block, see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982). Though in your case it doesn't matter much, the bottleneck will be reading and processing the input file.
- As the kind of input data is known, we can avoid `Export-Csv`'s complexities (like escaping rules) and create the CSV directly using simple string operations and `Set-Content`. Again, won't really make a difference here, but might still be good to know for other cases that are more output-heavy.

Comment: I just ran a test using a sample file of 4 million telephone numbers.  
  
1) The solution with ReadLines and Group-Object took 22.04 sec  
2) The solution with Switch and ForEach-Object took 7.5 sec.

Comment: @Matteru Thanks for testing! I just did a few other tests and seems like the biggest gain comes from replacing `Group-Object` by `hashtable`. Comparing `switch` vs. `ReadLines` it seems that `ReadLines` is slightly faster on PS 5.1 while on PS 7.3, `switch` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$input = @"
area,number
201,44556
202,34529
201,44556
202,34529
201,44556
202,34529
201,44556
202,34529
"@

$table = $input | ConvertFrom-Csv
$table | Format-Table

$groups = $table | Group-Object {$_.area}

$outputTable = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($group in $groups)
{
$group | Format-Table

   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName area -NotePropertyValue $group.Name

   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName count -NotePropertyValue $group.Count

   $outputTable.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$outputTable | Format-Table
```

Comment: Can you clarify the initial part of the code? Does it ask for listing all the data that needs to be read?

Comment: Just created test data.  So I'm reading from a string instead of a file.  You can use Import-CSV instead to read from file.

Comment: As it concerns **250 million lines**, I would use the PowerShell Pipeline ([One-at-a-time processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines#one-at-a-time-processing)) as it is supposed to (by *not* assigning the results `$table =` which chokes the pipeline and loads everything in memory). Just `Import-Csv .\Input..txt -Header area |Group-Object -Property area -NoElement` should do.

Comment: As an aside, do not use the [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input) variable (without explanation) as it is an preserved automatic variable.